How to use covariant return types in interfaces
I would like to understand if it is possible to use covariant return types in interfaces in C#.
I have an interface like the one in the following code snippet and two classes which implement the interface. I would like to constraint the classes to implement the method Method but I need it to return an object of type corresponding to the concrete classes.
The following code snippet shows what i would like to obtain.
public interface Interface<T>
{
    public Interface<T> Method();
}

public class ClassA : Interface<int>
{
    public ClassA Method() {...}
}

public class ClassB : Interface<string>
{
    public ClassB Method() {...}
}

I've read online about covariance in return types in interfaces in C# but i've not found any solution for my problem, yet. I have also read some similar questions which propose some workarounds but they don't fit for my case: i need to use Method and then being able to call the other methods of ClassA or ClassB on the returned object without the need of a cast.
Is it allowed in C#? How could i solve my problem?
Thank you in advance.

You can have more than one type Param. interface IMyInterface<TConcrete, TVal> where TConcrete : IMyInterface<TConcrete, TVal> { TConcrete Method (); } and then class ClassA : IMyInterface<ClassA, int> { ...

You can, but the extra type parameter makes the interface more difficult to consume. TConcrete is also likely to be irrelevant to the consumer.

Well the overall requirement is rather peculiar to me...

@Fildor Why so? The example is obviously simplified for brevity, but covariant returns have genuine use cases.

Because... how do I explain?  ... for the interface method to know what type to return, if that type is supposed to be the implementing type, it would need to know what the type is that it is implemented by. So it would be natural to me to let it know by giving it a type Param. For the consumer, if they expect that concrete implementing type directly, I would assume they already know which type it is and thus won't have a hard time. Based on this, I don't really see the need for covariant return. But maybe the example is undercomplex, admitted.

"TConcrete is also likely to be irrelevant to the consumer." - that's the exact opposite of what OP writes: "i need to use Method and then being able to call the other methods of ClassA or ClassB on the returned object without the need of a cast." @JohnathanBarclay

@Fildor OK, I interpret that as wanting to get a specific type though an instance of that specific type, rather than via the interface, but you could be correct.

@JohnathanBarclay I could also be wrong. So, "depends" I would say.

Covariant return types are currently only supported via inheritance (as of C#9).
Interface method implementation covariance is currently proposed as a future  enhancement.
For now, you can use explicit implementations to work around the limitation:
public class ClassA : Interface<int>
{
    public ClassA Method() {...}
    Interface<int> Interface<int>.Method() => Method();
}

With this approach, you can call Method on an reference to ClassA to get a ClassA, and also ensure the interface contract is honoured.
